# Pattern compile throwing java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException

Tags: java, regex, exception

i have following

```
Pattern loPattern = Pattern.compile(someText.toLowerCase(), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
```

this line throws exception if `someText` has pattern like `e[l`

this `someText` can contain characters **[a-z][A-Z][0-9]!@#$%^&;*()_+=|{}[];:'"<>;,.?/`~§ -**

whats the possible solution for it?

Comment: Could you post [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: It really does not make sense to lowercase the pattern **and** match case insensitive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the `Pattern.LITERAL` flag so the meta-characters are not translated in the expression

```
Pattern loPattern = 
    Pattern.compile(someText, 
       Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.LITERAL);
```